# Why is Jackson giving me an error when I try to write out a path?

Tags: java, json, jackson

My example code:

```
private void saveData() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
        mapper.writeValue( new File ( "test.json" ), Paths.get( "/home/joshua/") );
    } catch ( IOException e ) {
        System.out.println ( "Unable to write json" );
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The error: 
`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Direct self-reference leading to cycle (through reference chain: sun.nio.fs.UnixPath["parent"]->sun.nio.fs.UnixPath["parent"]->sun.nio.fs.UnixPath["root"])`

Why is Jackson breaking when I try to write out a path?

Comment: Because a Path is not a data structure that Jackson can deal with. It treats it like any other class, and, as the error message says, the internal structure of a Path has cycles that can't be transformed to JSON. Just transform your path to a String. Or write a custom serializer.